# Estimate Specific Value in MGCV

Tags: plot, gam, mgcv

I am attempting to run a GAM model and obtain a precise estimate, at a given value based on the recommendation from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843654/extracting-data-used-to-make-a-smooth-plot-in-mgcv) for the package mgcv. When using the predict function, the results do not match the estimates from GAM.

Here's my model that I am interested in:

```
mod <- gam(y~s(a, by=b), data = dat)
```

When I obtain results using:

```
plot(mod)
```

The results are different than when I try to estimate a single plot point on variable a using the following method:

```
pdat <- with(dat,
             data.frame(a = 0,
                        b = mean(b,na.rm = TRUE)))
pred <- predict(mod, pdat, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)
pdat <- transform(pdat, fitted = pred$fit)
pdat <- transform(pdat, upper = fitted + (1.96 * pred$se.fit),
                  lower = fitted - (1.96 * pred$se.fit))
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error I found the answer to my question. It seams, rather than the mean of the values because of my by variable I need to replace b with 1 -- this obtains the exact values in the graph.

Perhaps this will help someone else in the future.